# Pymongo error when inserting nested object

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I get the following error

```
bson.errors.InvalidDocument: Cannot encode object: {'height': u'149 - 152 cm',
     'length': u'354 - 356 cm',
     'tank': u'35 L',
     'width': u'165 cm',
     'year': u'2014 - 2015'}
```

when trying to insert into a collection the following document

```
{'_id': 6513,
 'details': {'height': u'149 - 152 cm',
 'length': u'354 - 356 cm',
 'tank': u'35 L',
 'width': u'165 cm',
 'year': u'2014 - 2015'},
 'make': u'Volkswagen',
 'name': u'up!',
 'price': u'10.950'}
```

by using the last version of pymongo. Do you know why? I insert the document with

```
collection.insert(dict(item))
```

Comment: you're inserting `dict(item)` why? is `item` not already a `dict`?

Comment: item is an scrapy item

Comment: So it's possible that the value of the 'details' key is not a `dict` as well right? In that case, you should do item['details'] = dict(item['details']) before inserting

Comment: Sir_Fz yeah it works